# Default sharing access levels for account owner

Tags: account, sharing, owd

This was the exact question that someone asked long back ago on [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395409/where-are-default-account-owner-sharing-access-levels-defined). Account owner defaults to following sharing access levels in my org.

1. Account Access: Full Access
2. Contact Access: Read / Write
3. Opportunity Access: Read Only
4. Case Access: Read Only

The OWD for all those 4 objects are *Private*. can someone explaing where these access levels being defined?

Comment: Im seeing the same behavior and its rather surprising to me, given that all are private.  I ran a full sharing rule recalculation and nothing changed.  However, for me, default case access IS private, so...it must be settable - somewhere?

Comment: well this is interesting, as i change the record owner, the values for contact, opp, and case change too.  So it seems like these fields *reflect* the sharing access granted to the owner, but *also allow you to set it*.  spooky.

Answer (score 1):

You need to navigate to Setup--> Security Controls --> Sharing Settings

[image]

As you are a System Administrator you are overriding all the default permissions at the OWD level. A System Administrator Can configure and customize the application. Has access to all functionality that does not require an additional license. For example, administrators cannot manage campaigns unless they also have a Marketing User license. Can manage price books and products. Can edit any quota, override forecasts, and view any forecast. Being a System Administrator you have full access to the Org

Comment: Do you mean that those permissions come from default OWD? They all are set to private in my org. Thanks.

Comment: Those are not Private by default. Someone might have updated those settings in your org.

Comment: so I just created a test account record ignoring the existing records. As per your answer, I would expect the account owner should have 'private' set to opportunity, case and contact access levels. But it doesn't, they still have the same access levels as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Do you have a System Administrator profile? or you might be having "Modify All Data" permission on your profile.

Comment: Yes, I am on sys-admin profile

Comment: System Administrator - Can configure and customize the application. Has access to all functionality that does not require an additional license. For example, administrators cannot manage campaigns unless they also have a Marketing User license. Can manage price books and products. Can edit any quota, override forecasts, and view any forecast. Being a System Administrator you have full access to the Org.

Comment: the poster isn't asking about why his user can see the records, he's asking about what's driving the default values for the owner sharing rule as they don't seem to correspond to the OWD, i ran into this previously and never got an answer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is set at the role level.  Look at the role and you can set contact case and opportunity access.  That is why it was changing when I changed owner.

It appears that this sharing also rolls up the hierarchy, but I need to test to confirm that this does and that role based sharing rules do not.